# CoderByte JavaScript Letter Changes - first steps

Tags: javascript, arrays, counter

For those familiar with this quiz, I'm trying to take a string argument and convert each letter to the letter that follows in the alphabet. EG, the argument "abc" should become "bcd".

The first portion of my code works. It takes the first letter of the argument and converts it. Now I'm trying to do this for each letter of the argument and then concatenate the results into one string as the output. This part isn't working. I'm getting the error, **"SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;"**

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 
   var string = str.toLowerCase()
   var alphabet = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l",       
   "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
   var n = 0;
   var output = "";
   var currentLetter = string[n];
   var currentAlphaPos = alphabet.indexOf(currentLetter);
   var nextAlphaPos = currentAlphaPos + 1; 
   var nextAlpha = alphabet[nextAlphaPos];

   //the code above this works. The code below results in an error

  while (i = 1;i < string.length; i++){
      output += nextAlpha;
      n += 1;
   };

   return output;
}
```

I'm a beginner, so thanks in advance.

Comment: You are never updating `currentLetter`, `currentAlphaPos`, `nextAlphaPos`, or `nextAlpha`. Those values don't change just because you've changed `n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the `while` and `for` loops.

You are trying to do `for (iterator; condition; step)`; the `while` syntax is simply `while (condition)`.

Comment: Thank you! Weary beginner eyes over here. It's still not working, but I'm closer. It now outputs a bunch of the same letter. IE, [var n] isn't progressing, which I tried to do in the [for] loop.

Comment: Update: I think I got it. I moved a bunch of the "global VAR's" *into* the [for] loop. That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: You don't have any global variables; moving the variable assignments which need to change on each iteration will solve your problem though, yes.

Comment: Style tip: capitalized function names are for constructors. `function letterChanges(str) {}` is preferable here.

Comment: thanks for the style tip. The funny thing is that [LetterChanges] is actually CoderBytes' built-in code. I thought it was weird as well.

Comment: I don't know what CoderBytes is but maybe you shouldn't use it.